# C meta with cmake dependency issues

Tags: python, c++, c, cmake, metadata

I'm working on a project that mixes C and C++ (in different files of course). As apart of debugging, I want the ability to print and save/load data structures from the C code. Naturally, I want that code to be auto generated and I have a couple of scripts that actually manage the job ok by parsing the C code through python and spitting out functions to do the job by reading the structure members.

However, there is abit of a problem - I'm using cmake to build the project which lets me auto-build these, but the issue comes when I look at the 'dependency' side of things - i.e. because cmake doesn't know my script is parsing the code (and hence the header files) and as such the output is dependent on the script, the C file, AND the headers it imports and the headers they import, etc.

I have found how to get gcc to give me the current dependency tree for a given file, but I realised there is a problem integrating that with cmake - i.e. once I've declared the dependencies of the generated files, cmake won't automatically recheck to see if the dependency list has been changed. So, if the C file developer adds a new include statement somewhere, it will recompile once, but won't recompile for changes to the new header.

For example:

Initially,

`A.c ----includes----> B.h`

*compiles*

Then A is modified so that

`A.c ----includes----> B.h
                |
                └---> C.h`

BUT future changes to C.h WILL NOT cause the script to be re-run as cmake has an out of date view of what the output dependencies are.

Is there a way to solve this in cmake?

Alternatively, is there a supported way to get C/C++ meta-data from the source code that is already supported by cmake that I'm not aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a thought - I could get my script to dump the dependency list as a .cmake file that my build imports - this would trigger cmake to re-run every time the dependencies are changed, which would keep the dependency information up to date.

Anyone see problems with this?